# Parse json answer from Redmine API with PHP

Tags: php, json, rest, curl, redmine

I'm trying to parse a JSON answer from Redmine API and I don't know how to get to the parts of the array.

Here is the code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://login:password@redmine.server/redmine/issues.json?cf_2=12345');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

$data = json_decode($response);
```

When I make a var_dump($data), the answer looks like this:

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#1853 (14) { ["id"]=> int(96) ["project"]=> object(stdClass)#1852 (2) { ["id"]=> int(68) ["name"]=> string(7) "Test.......
```

So, when I make a for loop, I would like to access the parts of the array:

```
foreach($data as $issues){
    var_dump($issues["id"]);
}
```

And so on. Any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me...

The culprit was here:

```
$data = json_decode($response);
```

Should be:

```
$data = json_decode($response,true);
```

Now I get a proper PHP array.